# Cannot write to file more than once. Receive Errno 13 Permission Denied

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I'm getting a permissions error but I'm writing some data to a .mp3 file using google's text to speech api. Here is the code I took from them and put inside a function.

```
"""Synthesizes speech from the input string of text or ssml.

Note: ssml must be well-formed according to:
    https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/
"""
from google.cloud import texttospeech

def gen_speech(num):
    # Instantiates a client
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    # Set the text input to be synthesized
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=f'{num}')

    # Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
    # voice gender ("neutral")
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='ja-JP',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)

    # Select the type of audio file you want returned
    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    # Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
    # voice parameters and audio file type
    response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        # Write the response to the output file.
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Here is my code for app.py.

```
from speech import gen_speech
import random
from playsound import playsound

def get_input():
    user_input = input("Enter the number: ")
    return user_input


def main():
    while True:
        num = random.randint(0, 5)
        gen_speech(num)  # generate speech
        playsound('output.mp3')
        user_input = int(get_input())
        if user_input != num:
            print('Incorrect. Listen closely')
            while user_input != num:
                playsound('output.mp3')
                user_input = int(get_input())
        print('Correct!')
        break
    gen_speech(10)
    playsound('./output.mp3')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The purpose of this program is just to enter what you hear. For some reason, writing to output.mp3 in gen_speech() works the first time it is called but the second time it gets called (whether that be in the if statement in the while loop or on another iteration of the while loop) I receive this permissions error. Unfortunately, you cannot use os.chmod() to change write and execute bits to 7's either. Does anyone know how I can change permissions on this file for it to work and/or why I may be getting this error? Also worth noting, Python creates the file too. I do not create it beforehand.

Comment: wild guess: ``playsound`` is blocking the file. What happens if you remove **all** calls to ``playsound`` and run your app?

Comment: You are correct. I suspected that too but looked at the source and didn't see anything that would block it. Maybe I didn't look hard enough. That's a bummer. Thanks